# Knowledge Domain ability Lore Keep and action type

Tags: pathfinder-1e, domains

I am trying to figure out how the [Lore Keeper](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo-domains/knowledge-domain/) ability works but its lacking details.

Lore Keeper

> You can touch a creature to learn about its abilities and weaknesses. With a successful touch attack, you gain information as if you made the appropriate Knowledge skill check with a result equal to 15 + your cleric level + your Wisdom modifier.

How do I use this touch attack? Is it a standard action? Does it happen if I make a regular or full attack with a unarmed or natural attack?

In this case, I am a druid with the ancient guardian archetype, which has the domain as one of the choices, as well as a monk. So if I were to attack something and hit with my unarmed strike, either as a standard or full round action, would I benefit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is usually defined as a **Standard Action** on the ability that grants those powers. Cleric [domain powers](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/) are no exception:

> In addition, a cleric gains the listed powers from both of her domains, if she is of a high enough level. Unless otherwise noted, **activating a domain power is a standard action**.